# Memory leak in SpannableString, dependent on WHERE I put the ClickableSpan

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, spannablestring

So,....

I've got this code (`onStart`):

```
ss = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.legal_user_acceptance_disclaimer));
ss.setSpan(clickableSpanTermsOfUse, 32, 44, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

which leak the parent-`Activity` (those lines are in).

if I change nothing but the numbers:

```
ss.setSpan(clickableSpanTermsOfUse, 49, 63, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

the leak disappears.

`clickableSpanTermsOfUse` (`memory leak` is the same with a normal `ClickableSpan`):

```
clickableSpanTermsOfUse = new NoRefCopySpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity.this, PrivacyStatement.class));//, TermsOfUse.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };

public class NoRefCopySpan extends ClickableSpan implements NoCopySpan {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) { }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
    }

}
```

I tried around a lot, using `SpannableStringBuilder` instead of `SpannableString`, hooking somewhere else into the `lifecycle`, manually setting all values to `null`, the only thing that makes a difference is, WHERE I put the `ClickableSpan`.

What's going on here na dhow can I get rid of the memory leak?